# Multilanguage site works on localhost but not on the Internet

Tags: php, html, web, multilingual

I made a website, with 3 lang on it, and site works fine (localhost) but when I upload it, default lang is EN and whenever I change lang on the web, let's say from EN to FR, page goes on that lang in this case on FR and redirect me on home page and all text on site is on FR, that's ok, but after that, when I try to click on let's say about us, then on it's own change it back to default lang, and show me that page (about us) but on default lang...
Here is sample of code how it's look...

This is select.php and I include_once this file on every page...

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];

// register the session and set the cookie
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
{
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
$lang = 'en';
}

switch ($lang) {
  case 'en':
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
  break;

case 'fr':
  $lang_file = 'lang.fr.php';
  break;

case 'de':
  $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
   break;

default:
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';

}

include_once 'lang/'.$lang_file;
```

**This is lang.en.php...**

```
$lang = array();

// menu
$lang['txt1'] = 'Home';
$lang['txt2'] = 'About Us'; 
$lang['txt3'] = 'Services'; 
$lang['txt4'] = 'Contact';
```

It's the same for other two languages...

**and I simply put in index.php this...**

```
<ul>
    <li><a  href="index.php"><em><b><?php echo $lang['txt1'];?></b></em></a></li>
    <li><a  href="about.php"><em><b><?php echo $lang['txt2'];?></b></em></a></li>
    <li><a  href="services.php"><em><b><?php echo $lang['txt3'];?></b></em></a></li>
    <li><a  href="contact.php"><em><b><?php echo $lang['txt4'];?></b></em></a></li>
</ul>
```

When is on default lang, I can navigate fine, I can go on any page without problems, but problem is when I try to change site into other language(s),
let's say I'm on page www.example.com/about.php and I want to see this page on let's say FR, site will redirect me, on www.example.com/index.php?lang=fr (this is ok) and then I can see FR lang on site but only on home page, but when I try to go on www.example.com/about.php then site put back default lang, in this case EN...

Strange thing is that this script works fine on localhost...
Any idea why?

#### Update:

```
OUTPUT:
Array ( [lang] => lang value to put in session [something_1] => something value to put in session )
Array ( [lang] => new lang value but not set in session [something_1] => something value to put in session )

<?php

session_start();
$lang = "lang value to put in session";
$something = "something value to put in session";
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
$_SESSION['something_1'] = $something;
print_r($_SESSION);
$lang = "new lang value but not set in session";
$something = "new something value but not set in session";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

PHP shouldn't change the second array

```
Array ( [lang] => lang value to put in session [something_1] => something value to put in session )
Array ( [lang] => new lang value but not set in session [something_1] => something value to put in session )
```

It should look like this:

```
Array ( [lang] => lang value to put in session [something_1] => something value to put in session )
Array ( [lang] => lang value to put in session [something_1] => something value to put in session )
```

Any idea why?

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. Are the session values getting saved? We can't tell that just from the code, you'll need to provide more detailed info

Comment: please stop messing with the formatting of your question. It is completely unreadable. We have been fixing it and you are rolling back the changes. Don't use "`" for formatting large code blocks. Use 4 indented spaces before each line of code. You could also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for making my post more readable...

Answer (score 0):

- Be sure your files does NOT echo anything before settings the session
- if your saving files as UTF , be sure it's UTF without BOM
- disable display_errorsin ini file . try `ini_set('display_errors',false);`

i hope this helps , i encountered this problem many times .

Comment: 1 - session_start() is on top of every file, 2 - Every file is UTF-8, 3 - Where to put that? In which file, I did in header.php below the select.php, and still don't work properly...

Comment: there are 2 types of UTF-8 , try installing http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ (notepad++) , and open the file in it , in the menu select 'encoding>utf-8 without BOM' , as the UTF-8 that is with BOM adds some extra bits to the start of the file that even may be interpretted by the browser as a new line !

Comment: and try to view source of that page , there might be some text printed somehow

Comment: It's already set to UTF-8 without BOM, and there is no whitespaces, text etc... I think it's server problem... I'll try to find out more about that... Btw thanks.

Comment: try to use this doctype : `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` , or give me a link i will check it up for you